# Python Tkinter: Change scale trough to be multicolor gradient

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, slider

I'm creating a `Scale` slider that will be used to select a Hue. I am wondering if I can set the trough to be more than one color, so it would look something like the google color slider. [image: Google Slider]

I'm aware of the `troughcolor` config option for `Scale`, but it only accepts one color. I have a `Hue2RGB` function that will make getting the color gradient easy, but I need a way to color the trough pixel-by-pixel. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688639/how-do-i-make-a-color-selection-scale-in-tkinter), but the poster doesn't explain how they get the color on the trough in the first place. For those more familiar with Tkinter, could I subclass `Scale` and and override some sort of `draw_trough` function?

Comment: You can have a look at gradientbar.py in the [tkcolorpicker](https://github.com/j4321/tkColorPicker/tree/master/tkcolorpicker) module. As Bryan Oakley suggested, it is made from a Canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering if I can set the trough to be more than one color

No, you can't.

That being said, tkinter does give you all the tools to create your own component that looks like that if you want to put in the effort (eg: creating the slider out of canvas objects).

Comment: Thanks for telling me it's not possible as stated. I don't want to waste time going down a rabbit hole. I've taken @j_4321's advice and will be using something like the gradientbar.